# Use a EX2700 wifi range extender's Ethernet for connection

Tags: wireless-networking, range

I have a router connected to the Internet, an EX2700 wifi extender connected to that router's network, and a Windows 10 PC without a wifi adapter.  Can I do this and if so what must I do to make it happen?  It does not appear to work automatically.

[router] ))) [extender]---ethernet---[PC]

Comment: What setup have you done on the extender?

Comment: I have set it up using the built-in site to connect to my main wifi and transmit its own wifi.

Comment: On Windows 10, can you open Settings > type in "Network properties" > click the result > click "copy" at the bottom. Then, edit your post and insert the text? I am trying to see if it is Windows or not. Thank you.